# Check whether a Menu item is enabled or disabled in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, menu

Is there any way to check whether a menu item is enabled or not in tkinter?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

def disable_menus():
    test_menu.entryconfig("Sub-Menu 1" , state=DISABLED)
    test_menu.entryconfig("Sub-Menu 2" , state=DISABLED)

def enable_menus():
    test_menu.entryconfig("Sub-Menu 1", state="normal")
    test_menu.entryconfig("Sub-Menu 2", state="normal")

def check_state():
    # Code to check if the sub-menus are enabled or not
    pass

disable_button = Button(root , text = "Disable Menus" , command = disable_menus)
disable_button.grid(row = 0 , column = 0 , padx = 20 , pady = 20)

enable_button = Button(root , text = "Enable Menus" , command = enable_menus)
enable_button.grid(row = 1 , column = 0)

check_button = Button(root , text = "Check State" , command = check_state)
check_button.grid(row = 0 , column = 1)

main_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=main_menu)

test_menu = Menu(main_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label = "Test Menu 1" , menu = test_menu)

test_menu.add_command(label = "Sub-Menu 1")
test_menu.add_command(label = "Sub-Menu 2")

mainloop()
```

Here when I click on the `check_button`, I want to check whether the menu items are enabled or not.

Is there any way to achieve this in tkinter?

It would be great if anyone could help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `menu.entrycget(index, option)` this will return the value of the option.
In your case:

```
test_menu.entrycget("Sub-Menu 1", 'state')
```

This will return the state of the "Sub-Menu 1".